# Updating Date on GetDate Function From Different Table

Tags: sql-server, tracking, getdate, data-tracing

I'm fairly new to writing SQL and I consider myself quite novice in all facets of programming. I have been working on a sql project for a friend and wanted to track changes. I'm using SQL Server and Transact-SQL. Here's the table format and relationships at its most basic sense:

Table1: HouseNo, StreetName, TerritoryNo(FK)

Table2: TerritoryNo(PK), Tracking

Relationship Between Tables: TerritoryNo

Basically, I want the Tracking column for a TerritoryNo in Table2 to be updated with the getdate() function whenever there is a change to any corresponding row in Table1. How could this be acheived? Or is this even possible?

Thanks for your assistance and even reviewing this topic!!

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server ?

Comment: Hi there, I am using SQL-Server @MateoBarahona

Comment: What you're looking for is a [Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: If you are using a stored procedure for your updates you could add a second update to update Table2.

Comment: I would add an update statement for the Tracking column within the stored procedure that updates Table1 rather then use a trigger. Triggers do not scale well and make troubleshooting more difficult.